# How set text field and button at center of view automatically when mode change?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton, uitextfield, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to set text field , uibutton, label and image view at the center of UIView automatically when i change mode of view either land scape or portrait mode.My mean that when i change orientation then text field and button and image automatically set in center of view.  How i set them by using interface builder or dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write code in this method

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return YES;
}


-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
        //write your code specific to orientation
    }
    else if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
            //write your code specific to orientation
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmtically you can set the `center` property of your views. Do that when you detect interface orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

you have to constrcut two different frames for that. One for normal view and other for landscape view . Then in the interFaceOrientationChange method u have to set the new frame.

Answer (score 0):

use button.center = view.center property.

Answer (score 0):

use `autoresizing` property on UIView and set it accordingly ... most convenient way of doing it